# Swift/iOS component for label with clickable text buttons

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, swift, ios

So I'm creating a component based on `UILabel`, which I'm calling `RichLabel`. The main goal is to add support for clickable links (multiple). It should also be possible to to differentiate between types of links, so I can handle them differently. For instance one link should open `ModalWindowA` and another `ModalWindowB`.

I have something that works, but it's not a very solid solution, and would love some input on the design.

### RichButton

`RichButton` is the different types of button/links I currently support in the RichText.

```
protocol RichButton {
  var id: String { get }
  var buttonTitle: String { get }
}

struct ProfileRichButton: RichButton {

  let id: String
  let buttonTitle: String

  init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, buttonTitle: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.buttonTitle = buttonTitle
  }

}

struct AttendeesRichButton: RichButton {

  let id: String
  let buttonTitle: String

  init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, buttonTitle: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.buttonTitle = buttonTitle
  }

}

struct MeetingRichButton: RichButton {

  let id: String
  let buttonTitle: String

  init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, buttonTitle: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.buttonTitle = buttonTitle
  }

}
```

### RichLabelComponent

RichLabelComponent is holding the data for the `RichLabelComponentView` and formats the text and highlights the clickable text.

```
protocol Component {
  var id: String { get }
}

struct RichLabelComponent: Component {

  let id: String
  let text: String
  let buttons: [RichButton]

  var formattedText: String {
    let buttonTitles = buttons.map { $0.buttonTitle }
    let formattedString = String(format: text, arguments: buttonTitles)
    return formattedString
  }

  var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: formattedText)
    let nsFormattedText = NSString(string: formattedText)
    attributedText.setAttributes([.font: Theme.regular(size: .large)], range: formattedText.whole)
    for button in buttons {
      let range = nsFormattedText.range(of: button.buttonTitle)
      let attributedButtonTitle = NSAttributedString(string: button.buttonTitle, attributes: [.foregroundColor: Theme.secondaryOrangeColor, .font: Theme.regular(size: .large)])
      attributedText.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attributedButtonTitle)
    }
    return attributedText
  }

  init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, text: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.text = text
    self.buttons = []
  }

  init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, text: String, buttons: RichButton...) {
    self.id = id
    self.text = text
    self.buttons = buttons
  }
}
```

### RichLabelComponentView

This is the view responsible for displaying the formatted label, and handles the tapGesture.

```
protocol RichLabelComponentViewDelegate: class {
  func richLabelComponentView(_ richLabelComponentView:   RichLabelComponentView, didTapButton button: RichButton, forComponent  component: RichLabelComponent)
}

class RichLabelComponentView: UIView {

  // MARK: - Internal properties

  private lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
  }()

  private lazy var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapHandler(gesture:)))
    return tapGestureRecognizer
  }()

  // MARK: - External properties

  weak var delegate: RichLabelComponentViewDelegate?

  var component: RichLabelComponent? {
    didSet {
      label.attributedText = component?.attributedText
    }
  }

  // MARK: - Setup

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    self.addSubviewsAndConstraints()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  private func addSubviewsAndConstraints() {
    addSubview(label)

    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  // MARK: - Actions

  @objc func tapHandler(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let component = component, let delegate = delegate else {
      return
    }

    for button in component.buttons {
      let nsString = component.formattedText as NSString
      let range = nsString.range(of: button.buttonTitle)
      if tapGestureRecognizer.didTapAttributedText(label: label, inRange: range) {
        delegate.richLabelComponentView(self, didTapButton: button, forComponent: component)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the implementation which recognises if one of the text links/buttons where tapped:

```
extension UIGestureRecognizer {

  /**
   Returns `true` if the tap gesture was within the specified range of the attributed text of the label.

   - Parameter label:   The label to match tap gestures in.
   - Parameter targetRange: The range for the substring we want to match tap against.

   - Returns: A boolean value indication wether substring where tapped or not.
   */
  func didTapAttributedText(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    guard let attributedString = label.attributedText else { fatalError("Not able to fetch attributed string.") }

    var offsetXDivisor: CGFloat
    switch label.textAlignment {
    case .center: offsetXDivisor = 0.5
    case .right: offsetXDivisor = 1.0
    default: offsetXDivisor = 0.0
    }

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: .zero)
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedString)
    let labelSize = label.bounds.size

    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
    textContainer.size = labelSize

    let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
    let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)

    let offsetX = (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * offsetXDivisor - textBoundingBox.origin.x
    let offsetY = (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y
    let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)

    let locationTouchX = locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x
    let locationTouchY = locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y
    let locationOfTouch = CGPoint(x: locationTouchX, y: locationTouchY)

    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouch, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
  }
}
```

### How to use the component

```
let component = RichLabelComponent(text: "Hello %@. You are meeting with %@.", buttons: ProfileRichButton(buttonTitle: "Your Name"), AttendeesRichButton(buttonTitle: "Eve and Bob"))
let view = RichLabelComponentView()
view.component = component
view.delegate = self
```

I can then send `button`, and on the delegate method I can then `switch` on `button.self` and check for `case is ProfileRichButton` for instance, so I can know which type of link was clicked.

## The problems

What I don't like about this solution is for instance the need to use `NSString.range(of: "")` to set properties. If suddenly there are two links with same name, this won't work.

Any ideas how to improve this or restructure it in a more flexible and solid way?

Comment: What is `Theme` ?

Comment: I have problems to make it work. `indexOfCharacter` is always zero.

Comment: Theme just defines The colors and font used. Not important. But you should degine font size on attributedText for IT to work.

Comment: OK, works now (after defining `whole` :) – I just wonder: How does the delegate callback *which* button was tapped?

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot about that String extension. I updated my answer. I'm thinking maybe to just also send the `RichButton` with the delegate. ` func richLabelComponentView(_ richLabelComponentView: RichLabelComponentView, didTapButton button: RichButton, forComponent component: RichLabelComponent)`